# Computing the bourbaki ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

By virtue the [Griffith's paper](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-19/2/277.extract) and subsequently e.g. [Goto's paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-090-04/S0002-9939-1984-0733397-4/S0002-9939-1984-0733397-4.pdf) several examples of several desired class of Noetherian normal domains with specific finite length local cohomologies are constructed using the Bourbaki ideals. In order to compute some properties of these rings with Macaulay 2, I need to compute their Bourbaki ideals. does there exist any manuscript or any way to make this computation possible or easier?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is a Bourbaki ideal?

Comment: @abx: Let e.g. $R=K[X_1,...,X_n]$. Then the the Bourbaki ideal associated to an $R$-module $M$ is an ideal $I$ arising from an exact sequence $0\rightarrow F\rightarrow M\rightarrow I\rightarrow 0$ where $F$ is a finitely generated graded free $R$-module

Comment: I am not so sure if there is an easy way to convert a module into an ideal on Macaulay2. If the module $M$ has a rank, maybe even torsion free, then probably a generic choice of minimal generating set would produce a free submodule $F$ of rank one less than $M$. But here, your ideal $I$ may not be unique since it'd depend on the choice of the generators for $F$.

Comment: @Youngsu: Yes, in the Bourbaki exact sequence mentioned in my previous comment, as I know, $M$ should be torsion free and the free module $F$ satisfies $\text{rank}(F)=\text{rank}(M)-1$. Would you please kindly explain how can I obtain an ideal $I$ from a generic choice of minimal generating set of $M$ by means of Macaulay 2?

Comment: Let me try. Would you mind posting an example you have in mind?

Comment: @Youngsu: Lِet, e.g., $R=K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ with $n=8$. You can, easily, assume  that $M=L_1\bigoplus L_2$ where $L_1$ ($L_2$) is an $i$-th ($j$-th) (graded) syzygy of $R/(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ with $i\neq j$ and $2\le i,j\le n-2$.

Comment: Do you have an answer to this case? For instance, say $i = 2$, and $j = 3$?

Comment: @Youngsu: No, unfortunately. I don't know how can I compute the ideal $I$ even in that case.

Comment: Well, then I don't see why one needs to compute for $n = 8$. Can you give me an example you know the answer to?

Comment: @Youngsu: $n$ should be necessarily greater than or equal to $4$. I set $n=8$ to increase the dimension of $R/I$. Let me to try to find an example.

Comment: Aurora, please understand that I'm not trying to write a code which'd compute what you are interested. Instead, I'm trying write a code that would compute an example. So, it is better to try with examples which are of "small" size and you already know answers to.